# If $f\in C_\mathbb{R}([0,\pi])$ and $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ then $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\lVert f-\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sin(nx) \rVert_\infty < \epsilon$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If $f\in C_\mathbb{R}([0,\pi])$ and $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ then for all
> $\epsilon>0$ there exist $a_1,\dots, a_N$ s.t.
>
> $$\left \lVert f-\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sin(nx) \right \rVert_\infty < \epsilon$$
> Hint: Expand $f$ to be defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$ such that it is odd, and use trigonometric-polynomial approximation theorem (as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354603/from-stone-weierstrass-theorem-to-trigonometric-polynomial-approximation)).

I've defined $\hat{f}$ to be the extension of $f$ as described in the hint, and further extended it to $\mathbb{R}$ so that it is periodic with period $2\pi$. Now, for $\hat{f}$ I can use the trigonometric-polynomial approximation theorem, which states that there exists a function $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sin(nx)+b_n \cos(nx)$ such that:

$$\bigg \lVert \hat{f}(x)-\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sin(nx)+b_n \cos(nx)\bigg) \bigg \rVert_\infty < \epsilon$$

Now we observe that since the period is $2\pi$:

$$\bigg \lVert \hat{f}(x)-\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sin(nx)+b_n \cos(nx)\bigg) \bigg \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x \in [-\pi, \pi]} \bigg| \hat{f}(x)-\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sin(nx)+b_n \cos(nx)\bigg) \bigg|$$

Now I thought of somehow using even and odd parts of this difference function to conclude something about $\hat{f}|_{x\in [0,\pi]}$, but I'm unable to complete this intuition (assuming it is at all correct). Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Since you expanded $\;f\;$ in an odd manner, the  cosine part of that sum is zero...Have you already studied Fourier Analysis? Perhaps you're doing an introduction now to that.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why does the cosine part of the sum zero out? Wouldn't that depend on the $b_n$? I'm not seeing this somehow.. And indeed an introduction :)

Comment: How otherwise would be that aproximation to the odd expansion of $\;f\;$ and odd function...? It'd be, perhaps, a good idea to write down explicitely what do you call trigonometric-polynomial approximation theorem to...

Comment: Agree - added a reference now.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion follows from the Weierstrass theorem. The functions ${\sin(n+1)t\over \sin t}$ are of the form $$P_n(\cos t)={\sin(n+1)t\over \sin t},$$ where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomials (of degree $n$). Indeed, $P_0(x)=1,$ $P_1(x)= 2x.$ The rest follows from the trigonometric identity
$$2\cos t\sin nt=\sin(n+1)t+\sin(n-1)t.$$ Hence
$$\cos t {\sin nt\over \sin t}={\sin(n+1)t\over \sin t}+{\sin(n-1)t\over \sin t}$$
By subsituting $x=\cos t$ we obtain a recurrence relation
$$xP_{n-1}(x)=P_{n+1}(x)+P_{n-2}(x),\quad n\ge 2 $$
with initial conditions $P_0(x)=1$ and $P_1(x)=2x.$
The claim that $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ can be proved by induction.

Given $f\in C[0,\pi],$ let $g(x)=f(\arccos x).$ Then $g\in C[0,1].$ Therefore by the Weierstrass theorem for any number $\varepsilon>$ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $$|g(x)-p(x)|<\varepsilon, \quad 0\le x\le 1$$
After substituting $x=\cos t$ we get
$$|f(t)-p(\cos t)|<\varepsilon \qquad 0\le t\le \pi$$
Assume $\displaystyle p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n.$ Then
$\displaystyle p(\cos t)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\cos^nt.$ The trigonometric formula $$2\cos t\cos nt=\cos(k+1)t+\cos(k-1)t$$ implies that $$\cos^nt=\sum_{k=0}^nc_k\cos kt$$ for some coefficients $c_k.$ Therefore
$$p(\cos t)=\sum_{n=0}^N b_n\cos nt$$ for some coefficients $b_k.$

**Remark** The coefficients $c_k$ can be evaluated explicitly from the Newton's binomial identity
$\cos^nt={1\over 2^n}(e^{it}+e^{-it})^n.$